# Error : Attribute already defined with incompatible format in "attrs.xml" in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin for developing my application.
I've no problem with other platform such as UWP and iOs.

But when I try to build Android app I receive these errors:

[Errors shown in Visual Studio 2017](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0a6ky.png)

All these errors refers to "attrs.xml" file shown belowe :

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<resources>
   <declare-styleable name="DrawableStates">
      <attr name="state_indeterminate" format="boolean" />
   </declare-styleable>
   <declare-styleable name="SfCheckBox">
      <attr name="isthreestate" format="boolean" />
      <attr name="cornerradius" format="float" />
      <attr name="checked" format="enum">
         <enum name="unchecked" value="0" />
         <enum name="indeterminate" value="1" />
         <enum name="checked" value="2" />
      </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
   <declare-styleable name="SfSegmentedControl">
      <!--        The selected index of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentSelectedIndex" format="integer" />
      <!--        The backcolor of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentBackColor" format="color" />
      <!--        The border color of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentBorderColor" format="color" />
      <!--        The border thickness of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentBorderThickness" format="string" />
      <!--        The color of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentColor" format="color" />
      <!--        The segment padding of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentedPadding" format="string" />
      <!--        The segment height of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentedHeight" format="string" />
      <!--        The segment width of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentedWidth" format="string" />
      <!--        The stroke thickness of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentStrokeThickness" format="string" />
      <!--        The corner radius of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentCornerRadius" format="string" />
      <!--        The position of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentPosition" format="enum">
         <enum name="top" value="0" />
         <enum name="bottom" value="1" />
         <enum name="fill" value="2" />
         <enum name="border" value="3" />
      </attr>
      <!--        The displaymode of SfSegmentCondrol-->
      <attr name="segmentDisplayMode" format="enum">
         <enum name="image" value="0" />
         <enum name="text" value="1" />
         <enum name="imagewithtext" value="2" />
      </attr>
   </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Is there any problem for my "attrs.xml" file? 
I already tried to clean and rebuild solutions. Remove and adding again every package but errors persists.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you used the `SfSegmentedControl` from the Syncfusion like this link?
https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin-android/sfsegmentedcontrol/getting-started

Based on your error message, there are two issues.

**Issue1** is related to `segmentPosition` `segmentDisplayMode`.
I cannot find these attributes in `SfSegmentedControl`, you can refer to the following screenshot.If you want to define attributes in `attrs.xml`, `SfSegmentedControl` must have these attributes.
[image]
Solution: you could custom `SfSegmentedControl` to add these attributes.

**Issue2** is related to `SfCheckBox`, the format of `checked` attribute is `bool` not `enum` like this screenshot.

[image]
Solutions: change the format of `checked`

Comment: Thanks for your help :)

Actually I didn't use SfSegmentedControl in my project so I just cleaned the part referred to the library in my atts.xml and code worked !

Thanks again, have a nice day.